# Proper variable interpolation for $@

Tags: linux, bash, sh

```
#!/bin/bash
TARGET_ENV="$1"
shift
commandid=$(aws ssm send-command \
    --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" \
    --targets Key=tag:Name,Values=$TARGET_ENV \
    --parameters '{"commands":["su -c \"./'$@'\" - ec2-user"]}' \
    --query 'Command.CommandId' \
    --output text)

echo $commandid
```

(ssm_runner.sh)

My ec2 instance have a script called hello_world.sh that prints hello world and echo.sh which accepts parameters and echo it.

The following works

```
ssm_runner.sh dev hello_world.sh
```

but this one doesn't

```
ssm_runner.sh dev echo.sh hello
```

Comment: Consider how the "commands" parameter expands. `'...'$@'...'` becomes two strings.

Comment: so I should remove the quotations infront and after the $@?

Comment: No, nothing expands inside single quotes. As you have found, multiple levels of expansion are easy to get wrong. Consider finding a safer way to feed untrusted user input to su.

Comment: right now, I just want it so that I can pass a script file name and parameters to it via @$... I have zero to no knowledge on bash since I mainly use ruby on my work.. I would love it if you can lead me to an article that might help?

Comment: '...'$@'...' becomes two strings...
so does it become '...'echo.sh'...''...'hello...' ?

Comment: after expansion, you don't get `... --parameters word --query ...` you get `... --parameters word1 word2 --query` where `word1` ends with `echo.sh` and `word2` starts with `hello`. This is probably a syntax error.

Comment: Here is what I understand so far...
so I need to make whatevers inside $@ a string first and place it on --parameters?

Comment: so if $@ contains 2 arguments the "echo.sh" and "hello" I should make it as 1 string then pass it to to --paremeters alongside with -su -c and - ec2-user?

Comment: changing `'$@'` to `'"$*"'` will make this specific echo command work but I don't recommend that as a fix as it will still fail in other circumstances

Comment: this ssm_runner.sh does only call the .sh files in my ec2 instance the .sh files may have multiple parameter or no parameter. I think that is the only case I need to catch. so I think your suggestion maybe enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

TARGET_ENV="$1"
shift

# Compose a complete su command which can be safely interpreted with
# `eval` or `bash -c`.
printf -v cmd '%q ' "$@"
su="su -c ./${cmd% } - ec2-user"

# Create JSON using jq.
params=$(jq -c --arg su "$su" '.commands = [$su]' <<< '{}')

# Execute.
commandid=$(aws ssm send-command \
    --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" \
    --targets Key=tag:Name,Values="$TARGET_ENV" \
    --parameters "$params" \
    --query 'Command.CommandId' \
    --output text)

echo "$commandid"
```

Comment: should the two backwardslash ommited in "su -c ./${cmd% } - ec2-user"
I think my script would only work if it produce the following commands

Comment: "su -c \"./hello_world.sh\" - ec2-user"
or
"su -c \"./echo.sh hello\" - ec2-user"

Comment: I made it work by using your sampe and adding backward slash in front and after the ./${cmd% }

Comment: @joyfuljoy `%q` already escapes the words properly. Additional backward slashes should no longer be necessary unless you skipped some of the steps above like `jq`. It may occasionally fail sometimes if you do.